# Spring Security OAuth with JWK Example

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Does someone have a Spring Security OAuth 2 resource server (SP) example with JWT and asymmetric keys which is using JWK with a JWKS endpoint?

Thanks a lot.
Essey

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security OAuth 2 resource server can be configured to use JWK.
If you are using Spring Boot, you only need to use the property security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri to configure the JWKS endpoint.

That is the only special difference with the plenty of samples you might find online.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer.

I wrote an my own JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter which is using com.nimbusds.jose library to validate the token from the authentication header without calling any Keycloak API at all.
I would like to do the same with spring-security-oauth2 and spring-security-jwt. 
Is that possible? 

Thanks